# Is there any native function to convert json to url parameters?

Tags: javascript, json

I need convert json object to url form like: "parameter=12&asd=1"

I done with this:

```
        var data = {
            'action':'actualiza_resultado',
            'postID': 1,
            'gl': 2,
            'gl2' : 3
        };

        var string_=JSON.stringify(data);

        string_=string_.replace(/{/g, "");
        string_=string_.replace(/}/g, "");
        string_=string_.replace(/:/g, "=")
        string_=string_.replace(/,/g, "&");
        string_=string_.replace(/"/g, "");
```

But i wonder if there any function in javascript or in JSON object to do this?

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Use the [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) interface, which is built into [browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=urlsearchparams) and [Node.js starting with version 10](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#browser_compatibility), released in 2018.

```js
const myParams = {'foo': 'hi there', 'bar': '???'};

const u = new URLSearchParams(myParams).toString();

console.log(u);
```

**Old answer**: jQuery provides [`param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) that does exactly that. If you don't use jquery, take at look at the [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/serialize.js#L58).

Basically, it goes like this:

```
url = Object.keys(data).map(function(k) {
    return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k])
}).join('&')
```

Comment: There might be some people "keen on reinventing the wheel", because they are not using jQuery – for whichever good or bad reasons.

Comment: Not using jquery is not reinventing the wheel, heard of underscorejs?

Comment: Useful within a web [Worker()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker) context - where there's no jQuery

Comment: Update: You can use native URLSearchParams:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Comment: having trouble with nested objects with URLSearchParams

Comment: Note that URLSearchParams doesn't work on arbitrary JSON, it only works on a flat object with string values. For example, `new URLSearchParams({a: {b: 1}}).toString()` becomes `'a=%5Bobject+Object%5D'`.

Answer (score 25):

Using ES6 syntax:

```js
var data = {
  'action':'actualiza_resultado',
  'postID': 1,
  'gl': 2,
  'gl2' : 3
};

let urlParameters = Object.entries(data).map(e => e.join('=')).join('&');

console.log(urlParameters);
```

Comment: The question was about JSON objects. However, if the JSON contains array then the solution will produce good result as well but it will need parsing on the server side.
Ex:
var data = {
            'action':'actualiza_resultado',
            'postID': 1,
            'gl': 2,
            'gl2' : 3,
            'names': ['one','two', 'three']
        };
Result: "action=actualiza_resultado&postID=1&gl=2&gl2=3&names=one,two,three"

Comment: No need for this. There's a [built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525178/is-there-any-native-function-to-convert-json-to-url-parameters/14525299#14525299).

Comment: This is missing the `encodeURIComponent` needed for URL params that is in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14525299/327074) (and most of the other answers too)

Answer (score 14):

I made an implementation that support nested objects and arrays i.e.

```
var data = {
    users: [
    {
      "name": "jeff",
      "tasks": [
        "Do one thing",
        "Do second thing"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "rick",
      "tasks": [
        "Never gonna give you up",
        "Never gonna let you down"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Will be:

```
users[0][name]=jeff&users[0][tasks][0]=Do%20one%20thing&users[0][tasks][1]=Do%20second%20thing&users[1][name]=rick&users[1][tasks][0]=Never%20gonna%20give%20you%20up&users[1][tasks][1]=Never%20gonna%20let%20you%20down
```

So, here's the implementation:

```js
var isObj = function(a) {
  if ((!!a) && (a.constructor === Object)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
var _st = function(z, g) {
  return "" + (g != "" ? "[" : "") + z + (g != "" ? "]" : "");
};
var fromObject = function(params, skipobjects, prefix) {
  if (skipobjects === void 0) {
    skipobjects = false;
  }
  if (prefix === void 0) {
    prefix = "";
  }
  var result = "";
  if (typeof(params) != "object") {
    return prefix + "=" + encodeURIComponent(params) + "&";
  }
  for (var param in params) {
    var c = "" + prefix + _st(param, prefix);
    if (isObj(params[param]) && !skipobjects) {
      result += fromObject(params[param], false, "" + c);
    } else if (Array.isArray(params[param]) && !skipobjects) {
      params[param].forEach(function(item, ind) {
        result += fromObject(item, false, c + "[" + ind + "]");
      });
    } else {
      result += c + "=" + encodeURIComponent(params[param]) + "&";
    }
  }
  return result;
};

var data = {
  users: [{
      "name": "jeff",
      "tasks": [
        "Do one thing",
        "Do second thing"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "rick",
      "tasks": [
        "Never gonna give you up",
        "Never gonna let you down"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

document.write(fromObject(data));
```

Comment: Underrated answer! +1

Comment: but how to decode this encoded string?

Comment: Nesting is not specced and has many edge cases. See the [query-string module](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string#nesting). In most cases, you'll want to use the [URLSearchParams built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525178/is-there-any-native-function-to-convert-json-to-url-parameters/14525299#14525299).

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to serialize this object literal.

Better approach is something like:

```
function getAsUriParameters(data) {
   var url = '';
   for (var prop in data) {
      url += encodeURIComponent(prop) + '=' + 
          encodeURIComponent(data[prop]) + '&';
   }
   return url.substring(0, url.length - 1)
}
getAsUriParameters(data); //"action=actualiza_resultado&postID=1&gl=2&gl2=3"
```

Comment: You need to call `encodeURIComponent` on `prop` and `data[prop]` to properly encode them.  As written, this produces a broken URL when either key or value contains `'&'` or `'#'` or a `prop` contains `'='`.

Comment: The default `toString` will be called and probably the result will be something like `elem1%20elem2%20elem3`

Comment: @MikeSamuel: now there is a [built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525178/is-there-any-native-function-to-convert-json-to-url-parameters/14525299#14525299).

Answer (score 5):

Like @georg said, you can use [JQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) for flat objects.

If you need to process complex objects, you can use [JsonUri](http://guidj.github.io/jsonuri-py/), a python package that does just that. There is JavaScript library for it as well

*Disclaimer: I am the author of JSONURI*

**Edit**: I learned much later that you can also just base64 encode your payload - most languages as support for base64 encoding/decoding

Example

```
x = {name: 'Petter', age: 47, places: ['Mozambique', 'Zimbabwe']}
stringRep = JSON.stringify(x)
encoded = window.btoa(stringRep)
```

Gives you `eyJuYW1lIjoiUGV0dGVyIiwiYWdlIjo0NywicGxhY2VzIjpbIk1vemFtYmlxdWUiLCJaaW1iYWJ3ZSJdfQ==`, which you can use as a uri parameter

```
decoded = window.atob(encoded)
originalX = JSON.parse(decoded)
```

Needless to say, it comes with its own caveats

Comment: No need for a package nowadays. There's an isomorphic [built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525178/is-there-any-native-function-to-convert-json-to-url-parameters/14525299#14525299).

Answer (score 5):

Something I find nicely looking in ES6:

```
function urlfy(obj) {
    return Object
        .keys(obj)
        .map(k => `${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(obj[k])}`)
        .join('&');
}
```

Later update (same thing, maybe a bit cleaner):

```
const urlfy = obj => Object
    .keys(obj)
    .map(k => encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[k]))
    .join('&');
```

Comment: better than @Tareq

Comment: @kangear: even better - use [the built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525178/is-there-any-native-function-to-convert-json-to-url-parameters/14525299#14525299).

Answer (score 3):

> But i wonder if there any function in javascript

Nothing prewritten in the core.

> or json to do this?

JSON is a data format. It doesn't have functions at all.

---

This is a relatively trivial problem to solve though, at least for flat data structures.

Don't encode the objects as JSON, then:

```
function obj_to_query(obj) {
    var parts = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            parts.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
        }
    }
    return "?" + parts.join('&');
}

alert(obj_to_query({
    'action': 'actualiza_resultado',
    'postID': 1,
    'gl': 2,
    'gl2': 3
}));
```

There isn't a standard way to encode complex data structures (e.g. with nested objects or arrays). It wouldn't be difficult to extend this to emulate the PHP method (of having square brackets in field names) or similar though.

Comment: Perfect for what I needed: JSON to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" converter for Angular 2 Http.post body contents. Thanks.

Comment: @Quentin will it handle if one of the parameter is an array ?

Comment: @SanKrish — I was explicit about that in the answer which says "at least for flat data structures" as well as the entire last paragraph.

Comment: Now there's a [built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525178/is-there-any-native-function-to-convert-json-to-url-parameters/14525299#14525299).

Answer (score 3):

This one processes arrays with by changing the `name`into mutiple `name[]`

```
function getAsUriParameters (data) {
  return Object.keys(data).map(function (k) {
    if (_.isArray(data[k])) {
      var keyE = encodeURIComponent(k + '[]');
      return data[k].map(function (subData) {
        return keyE + '=' + encodeURIComponent(subData);
      }).join('&');
    } else {
      return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k]);
    }
  }).join('&');
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The conversion from a JSON string to a URL query string can be done in a single line:

```
const json = '{"action":"actualiza_resultado","postID":1,"gl":2,"gl2":3}';
const queryString = new URLSearchParams(JSON.parse(json)).toString();
```

`queryString` would then be set to `"action=actualiza_resultado&postID=1&gl=2&gl2=3"`.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution for Vanilla JavaScript:

```js
var params = Object.keys(data)
  .filter(function (key) {
    return data[key] ? true : false
  })
  .map(function (key) {
    return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key])
  })
  .join('&');
```

PS: The filter is used here to remove null or undefined parameters. It makes the url look cleaner.

Comment: No, this isn't the best solution for vanilla JS. That would be to [use the built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525178/is-there-any-native-function-to-convert-json-to-url-parameters/14525299#14525299), which had been around for a few years before this answer was written.

Answer (score 0):

The custom code above only handles flat data. And JQuery is not available in react native. So here is a js solution that does work with multi-level objects and arrays in react native.

```
function formurlencoded(data) {
const opts = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : {};

let sorted = Boolean(opts.sorted),
    skipIndex = Boolean(opts.skipIndex),
    ignorenull = Boolean(opts.ignorenull),
    encode = function encode(value) {
        return String(value).replace(/(?:[\0-\x1F"-&\+-\}\x7F-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|(?:[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF])/g, encodeURIComponent).replace(/ /g, '+').replace(/[!'()~\*]/g, function (ch) {
            return '%' + ch.charCodeAt().toString(16).slice(-2).toUpperCase();
        });
    },
    keys = function keys(obj) {
        const keyarr = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : Object.keys(obj);
        return sorted ? keyarr.sort() : keyarr;
    },
    filterjoin = function filterjoin(arr) {
        return arr.filter(function (e) {
            return e;
        }).join('&');
    },
    objnest = function objnest(name, obj) {
        return filterjoin(keys(obj).map(function (key) {
            return nest(name + '[' + key + ']', obj[key]);
        }));
    },
    arrnest = function arrnest(name, arr) {
        return arr.length ? filterjoin(arr.map(function (elem, index) {
            return skipIndex ? nest(name + '[]', elem) : nest(name + '[' + index + ']', elem);
        })) : encode(name + '[]');
    },
    nest = function nest(name, value) {
        const type = arguments.length > 2 && arguments[2] !== undefined ? arguments[2] : typeof value === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : typeof(value);
        let f = arguments.length > 3 && arguments[3] !== undefined ? arguments[3] : null;

        if (value === f) f = ignorenull ? f : encode(name) + '=' + f; else if (/string|number|boolean/.test(type)) f = encode(name) + '=' + encode(value); else if (Array.isArray(value)) f = arrnest(name, value); else if (type === 'object') f = objnest(name, value);

        return f;
    };

return data && filterjoin(keys(data).map(function (key) {
    return nest(key, data[key]);
}));
```

}

Comment: Beware that nesting is not specced and has many edge cases. See the [query-string module](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string#nesting). In most cases, you'll want to use the [URLSearchParams built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525178/is-there-any-native-function-to-convert-json-to-url-parameters/14525299#14525299).

Answer (score -1):

Based on georg's answer, but also adding `?` before the string and using ES6:

```
  const query = !params ? '': Object.keys(params).map((k, idx) => {
    let prefix = '';
    if (idx === 0) {
      prefix = '?';
    }
    return prefix + encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[k]);
  }).join('&');
```

Comment: No need for this, as there's a [built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525178/is-there-any-native-function-to-convert-json-to-url-parameters/14525299#14525299).

Answer (score -1):

Make a utility **if you have nodejs**

```
const querystring = require('querystring')

export function makeQueryString(params): string {
  return querystring.stringify(params)
}
```

import example

```
import { makeQueryString } from '~/utils'
```

example of use

```
  makeQueryString({
    ...query,
    page
  })
```

**Read the latest documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html).**

Comment: There's no need for this. There's a [built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525178/is-there-any-native-function-to-convert-json-to-url-parameters/14525299#14525299) and the `querystring` module has been deprecated in its favor.

Answer (score -1):

As most of the answers only convert flat objects to query parameters, I would like to share mine.

This function can handle flat objects, as well as nested arrays/objects while only using plain JS.

```
        function incapsulateInBrackets(key)
        {
            return '[' + key + ']';
        }

        function encode(object, isSubEncode=false, prefix = '')
        {
            let parts = Object.keys(object).map( (key) => {

                let encodedParts = [];

                if(Array.isArray(object[key]))
                {
                    object[key].map(function(innerKey, index){

                        encodedParts.push( encode(object[key][index], true, prefix + key + incapsulateInBrackets(index)));

                    });
                }
                else if(object[key] instanceof Object)
                {
                    Object.keys(object[key]).map( (innerKey) => {

                        if(Array.isArray(object[key][innerKey]))
                        {
                            encodedParts.push( encode(object[key][index], true, prefix + incapsulateInBrackets(key) + incapsulateInBrackets(innerKey)) );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            encodedParts.push( prefix + incapsulateInBrackets(key) + incapsulateInBrackets(innerKey) + '=' +  object[key][innerKey] );
                        }

                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    if(isSubEncode)
                    {
                        encodedParts.push( prefix + incapsulateInBrackets(key) + '=' + object[key] );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        encodedParts.push( key + '=' + object[key] );
                    }
                }

                return encodedParts.join('&');

            });

            return parts.join('&');
        }
```

Comment: Beware that nesting is not specced and has many edge cases. See the [query-string module](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string#nesting). In most cases, you'll want to use the [URLSearchParams built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525178/is-there-any-native-function-to-convert-json-to-url-parameters/14525299#14525299).

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggested function fully excludes Internet Explorer support. The provided answer should work on IE as well.