# JavaScript Object (JSON) to URL String Format

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, native

I've got a JSON object that looks something like

```
{
    "version" : "22",
    "who: : "234234234234"
}
```

And I need it in a string ready to be sent as a raw http body request.

So i need it to look like

```
version=22&who=234324324324
```

But It needs to work, for an infinite number of paramaters, at the moment I've got

```
app.jsonToRaw = function(object) {
    var str = "";
    for (var index in object) str = str + index + "=" + object[index] + "&";
    return str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
};
```

However there must be a better way of doing this in native js?

Thanks

Comment: That *is* "native JS".  The only thing you're forgetting is to call `escapeURIComponent` on each parameter name and its value (separately).

Comment: Oh, and if any of your properties may have array values, or values that are sub-objects, then your code would have to deal with that somehow (and exactly how would depend on what your server expects).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14525178/989121 and many others.

Comment: @thg435 +1 for the same solution as mine (to the letter!)

Comment: @Tibos: note that it doesn't handle nesting.

Comment: Or you can learn to use search engines (google or on stack), http://stackoverflow.com/a/14525299

Comment: Or....http://goo.gl/1koRcg

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**2018 update**

```js
var obj = {
    "version" : "22",
    "who" : "234234234234"
};

const queryString = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
    return `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`;
}).join('&');

console.log(queryString); // "version=22&who=234234234234"
```

**Original post**

Your solution is pretty good. One that looks better could be:

```
var obj = {
    "version" : "22",
    "who" : "234234234234"
};

var str = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){ 
  return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]); 
}).join('&');

console.log(str); //"version=22&who=234234234234"
```

+1 @Pointy for `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: Great! That helps a lot