# Java - JSON to URL

Tags: java, json, http, url, encoding

I get a **JSON** that I want to convert to **URL** with parameters for example:

`JSON`:

```
{
    "id" : "27",
    "name: : "Testing name"
}
```

`URL`:

```
id=27&name=Testing+name
```

I found some solutions but only in `Javascript` like this:

[JavaScript Object (JSON) to URL String Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910021/javascript-object-json-to-url-string-format)

But I want to use `Java`, not `Javascript`.

Any idea how I can make the transformation with Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1: convert JSON into `Map` with some library such as jackson.

```
public class JacksonMapper {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    private static final JacksonMapper INSTANCE;

    static 
    {
        INSTANCE = new JacksonMapper();
    }

    private JacksonMapper() {
        // not called
    }

    public static JacksonMapper getInstance() {

        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public Map<String, String> toMap(String jsonString) throws Exception {

        return mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>(){});

   }    
}
```

Step 2: a) if you are using Spring, you can simply pass the Map into [RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForEntity-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-) and call some of it's methods.

Step 2: b) If you are not using Spring, you could refer to Apache
[UriBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) and call method `addParameter` for each entry in map

Step 2: c) if you don't want to use library, you could iterate over map and build query string yourself.

Comment: I prefer Gson myself, but both would do the job.