# Angular 2 - Http Get request - pass json Object

Tags: javascript, http, angular

How can I do a http get request and pass an json Object

This is my json-Object

```
{{firstname:"Peter", lastname:"Test"}
```

and this Object I want to pass in the http request to get a list Of matched persons.

how is it possible? This example just shows a simple get request with  a json result. How do I have to modify it?

```js
//Component:

person:Person;
persons:Person [];
....
//Whre can I pass the person, here in the service??
getMatchedPersons(){
  this.httpService.getMatchedPersons().subscribe(
     data =>  this.persons = data,
    error => aller(error)
    );
 ); 
  

  //SERVICE
  //pass parameters?? how to send the person object here?
  getMatchedPersons(){
    return this.http.get('url').map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Comment: I suppose you would either have to use `http.post` instead, or pass the parameters in the querystring `http.get('url?firstname=$1&lastname=$2')`

Answer (score 5):

The `Http.get` method takes an object that implements [RequestOptionsArgs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html) as a second parameter.

The search field of that object can be used to set a string or a [URLSearchParams](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html) object.

An example:

```
 // Parameters obj-
 let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
 params.set('firstname', yourFirstNameData);
 params.set('lastname', yourLastNameData);

 //Http request-
 return this.http.get('url', {
   search: params
 }).subscribe(
   (response) => //some manipulation with response 
 );
```

Comment: I can't believe how complicated they've made a thing that should be extremely simple :(
And not just angular necessarily, but also javascript in general when needing to send variables with a get request. If we have 20 values what then? We have to loop through our object and manually do params.set(key, value)? I can't believe it... we should be able to just tell it "look, here's this object (or a stringified version). split it however you need to send it in get variables)" and that should be all. Why did they complicate things so much :(

Answer (score 5):

### For pure javascript:

You must serialize your json to a list of parameters:

```
?firstname=peter&lastname=test
```

and append it to the URL because `GET` requests have no body.

There are a few ways of converting JSON to QueryParameters.
They are addressed in this question: [Is there any native function to convert json to url parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525178/is-there-any-native-function-to-convert-json-to-url-parameters)

There you can choose the poison of your liking, mine was:

```
function obj_to_query(obj) {
    var parts = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            parts.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
        }
    }
    return "?" + parts.join('&');
}
```

But mind you that `GET` requests must obbey the URL limit that based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/773259) is recomended to stay under **2000** characters to be safe:

> RFC says 8000
>   IE8 and IE9 go as far as 2083
>   Search engines only read to 2048

### Using Angular2 URLSearchParams

With the same method of converting a plain JSON to arguments one could use `URLSearchParams` as suggested by Рома Скидан:

```
 let params: URLSearchParams = objToSearchParams(obj);

 return this.http.get('url', {
   search: params
 }).subscribe(
   (response) => //some manipulation with response 
 );

 function objToSearchParams(obj): URLSearchParams{
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            params.set(key, obj[key]);
    }
    return params;
 }
```

Comment: When you say: 'GET Requests have no body', this itself is wrong. Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body
Correct me if I misunderstood the context of your answer.

Comment: @AshishGoyal Exactly what I meant. By convention GET requests have their body part ignored.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want to stringify the json object

```
var json = JSON.stringify(myObj);

this.http.get('url'+'?myobj='+encodeURIComponent(json))
```

Comment: `myobj={"CompanyName":"Typhany&Co."}` ... break api comunication with a string containing `&`? Check.

Comment: Sure, don't forget to encode it `myobj= encodeURIComponent(myobj)`

Comment: This is the shortest and best answer. Thanks you. 

And on the backend, with node.js simply do `JSON.parse(req.query.obj)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `POST` request to pass objects to the server:

```js
//SERVICE
getMatchedPersons(searchObj: any){
    return this.http.post('url', JSON.stringify(searchObj))
                    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Then you can pass whatever JS object you want and send it to the server in your http request.

```js
getMatchedPersons(searchObj: any){
    this.httpService.getMatchedPersons(searchObj: any).subscribe(
        data =>  this.persons = data,
        error => alert(error);
    );
);
```

Comment: he does mention a GET request not POST

Comment: True, but you can't pass objects with GET - can I consider this a strategic downvote? ;)

Comment: You can, if you serialize them

Comment: Might as well switch to POST at this point, if you have to deserialize them on serverside.

Comment: This is what  @Arg0n suggested. But I would argue that it should be a GET, imagine this is a SEARCH/Filter criteria object, that in return GETs a list of search results

Comment: Are you suggesting because the method is called "GET" it should be used for getting things? Clearly you have never used any big APIs before like Twitter and the like, where you always POST.

Comment: @rinukkusu I agree with you that REST is not perfect, but I agree with AngJobs that object fetching and other requests that don't change stuff on server should be replayable, thus using get. If the object is simply a search filter and you use post for that, then you assume google is doing it wrong...

Comment: Definitely should stick to what the HTTP specs say... GET vs POST is something we shouldn't take lightly. One source for reasoning: https://medium.com/@suhas_chatekar/why-you-should-use-the-recommended-http-methods-in-your-rest-apis-981359828bf7

Answer (score 0):

Similar to AngJobs' but maybe more up-to-date??  Calling `encodeURIComponent` is not necessary.  Here's the Angular:

```
const stringifiedParams = JSON.stringify(this.filterParams);
return this.http.get<any[]>(`persons`, {params: {filter: stringifiedParams}});
```

On the server Node deserializes the params with `JSON.parse`:

```
filter = JSON.parse(req.query.filter.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's an easier way for flushing parameters

```
getMatchedPersons(myObject: any): Observable<Person[]> {
    return this.http.get<Person[]>('url', { params: { ...myObject } });
}
```

- The above code represents a function that accepts a `JSON` object `myObject` as a parameter.
- `HttpClient.get` method accepts an `options` paramter as its second paramter.
- The `options` parameter contains many useful keys, but we're only interested with the `params` key in our case.
- the value of `params` is `{ ...myObject }`, that is- we're using the spread operator to pass all `key:value` pairs from an object.

Refer that this will do the job, **and will not make the URL look ugly** with all those `?` and `key=value` and `&` characters, of course in either case those parameters won't be shown for the user since it's just an `HTTP` call, but still, if anyone is using a logger `interceptor`, they will have a clean log.