# Angular 2/4 : encode complex object within http.get search params

Tags: angular, http, encoding, query-string

How can I convert an object like that

```
{
    param1: "value1",
    param2: "value2",
    param3: ["value31" "value32"]    
}
```

into a querystring like that:

```
param1=value1&param2=value2&param3[]=value31&param3[]=value32
```

to be passed along an http.get reuquest?

Comment: [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525178/is-there-any-native-function-to-convert-json-to-url-parameters)

Comment: well, I was actually looking for a sort of native Angular API to do that, rather than a custom parsing function. Also, I have no intention of using jquery!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is something that you are looking for:

```js
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

let someObject = {
  param1: "value1",
  param2: "value2",
  param3: ["value31" "value32"]    
}

let queryString = new URLSearchParams();

for (const key in someObject) {
  queryString.set(key, someObject[key]);
}

queryString.toString();
```

You can find out more here [URLSearchParams API](https://angular.io/api/http/URLSearchParams) about the different options.

Comment: In this way what I get is:

param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value31,value32

which is different from what my remote service expects...

Comment: Then the only solution is doing your own custom parser.